# How to pass data between controllers using Xamarin+MVC+C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin+c#, working on a project which uses MVC + Xamarin + C#. I have a controller which will collect the required data which can be used for another screen too. While I am in the second screen, how can I access this data in more efficient way or how can I pass the data from first controller to the second controller?

Comment: You can use some mvvm pattern  : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/
Or https://mvvmcross.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement what you want it's to use a **ViewModel**. If you want to pass some parameters from a form and another, you can create different `ctor` for a page, something like:

```
public YourPage (int param1, string param2) {
    InitializeComponent ();
    <your code>
}
```

when you call this page you can use

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new YourPage(Id1, String1), true);
```